# How to use the access token to sign the POST request?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have an access token and i want to send the POST request and with the some feed in the body. The problem is i am able to get the GET request using the URLConnection but when i use the HttpPost I am not able to send the POST request.

I guess this problem has to do something with not being able to sign the POST request using HttpPost.

Can any one share the sample code for sending the POST request by signing it with the access token?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure, but it sounds like you want to use some kind of OAuth (access tokens, etc.)?! Then http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/ might be a little help for you.

Comment: I am using the oauth-signpost only but dont know how to use the access token which i am getting.

Comment: Read the manual! [This is the description](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/wiki/TwitterAndSignpost) for the complete handling from receiving tokens up to making requests. In this example OAuth with Twitter is described...

Comment: I am getting 401 Unauthorized message, don't know where i am going wrong.